# New inbox notification uses the StackAuth favicon for some reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, favicon

I found that new inbox notification use the [StackAuth](http://stackauth.com/favicon.ico) fav icon. Is this a new change or a bug?

I'm seeing it all the modern browsers so I don't think it's a caching issue, since source is pointing to the StackAuth favicon:

```
<img src="http://stackauth.com/favicon.ico" alt="stackauth.com">
```

[image: Odd.] [image: Curious]

Comment: Yup, happens here too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops, this was my fault.  I just did a rather large convergence of inbox code to consolidate what used to be 2 separate projects as part of fixing new top bar counts.  A bug crept in there specifically affecting Chat and Careers messages, for which a fix has already been deployed.

Comment: I'm still seeing that in my notifications - will it fix old notifications or are they there to stay?

Comment: Bump. This is happening to me, too. While browsing the Movies.SE, I get [this notification favicon[(https://prnt.sc/g3tojg), which belongs to the Music.SE